# installation of nokogiri 1.5.9 in bundle install

Tags: installation, bundle

i have this error when I run bundle install with nokogiri:

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb 
checking for libxml/parser.h... no
-----
libxml2 is missing.  please visit http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html for help with installing dependencies.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
        ....


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.5.9 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.5.9/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.5.9), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.5.9'` succeeds before bundling.
```

How may I rectify it?

> EDIT Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
>   Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
>   Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
>   Note : sélection de « libxslt1-dev » au lieu de « libxslt-dev »
>   E: Impossible de trouver le paquet  build-essential
>   E: Impossible de trouver le paquet  libxml2
>   E: Impossible de trouver le paquet  libreadline6-dev
>   E: Impossible de trouver le paquet  libssl-dev
>   E: Impossible de trouver le paquet  ncurses-dev
>   E: Impossible de trouver le paquet  postgresql-contrib
>   E: Impossible de trouver le paquet  libapr1
>   E: Impossible de trouver le paquet  libpcap-dev

Answer (score 10):

you need to install some libraries before nokogiri

In Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install libxslt-dev libxml2-dev
```

Comment: Thank's a lot but i have the same error :/  An error occurred while installing pcaprub (0.11.3), and Bundler cannot
continue.

Comment: try `gem install pcaprub` and then edit your question and paste the output from the executed command, or try again `bundle install`

Comment: try with `sudo apt-get install libpcap libpcap-dev`

Comment: Here is the result (dsl is in french)  Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
E: Impossible de trouver le paquet libpcap

Comment: Anybody ? :/ Please help me !

Comment: what ubuntu version have you installed? what app are you trying to run?

Comment: cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS \n \l
I try to run metasploit

Comment: ok, run the following `sudo apt-get -y install \
  build-essential zlib1g zlib1g-dev \
  libxml2 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev locate \
  libreadline6-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev git-core \
  libssl-dev libyaml-dev openssl autoconf libtool \
  ncurses-dev bison curl wget postgresql \
  postgresql-contrib libpq-dev \
  libapr1 libaprutil1 libsvn1 \
  libpcap-dev`

Comment: This is a guide of how to get metasploit working: https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/wiki/Setting-Up-a-Metasploit-Development-Environment

Comment: mmm, sorry, It looks like a misconfigured ubuntu repository

Comment: Do not you it is a way to settle this? I desperate

Comment: Maybe `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` and then run again the apt-get install but I'm not sure.

Comment: Sorry. I don't know how I can help you.

Comment: Thank you anyway :) , I'll try to uninstall all, it only remains for me to do it :/

Comment: It is

 

>  sudo yum install libxslt-devel libxml2-devel


for Centos

Answer (score 1):

This works for me :

```
$sudo apt-get install libpcap-dev
```

before

```
$ bundle install
```